# Styling latin letters

Tags: fonts

How do I produce this symbol:

[image]

I have tried, `\mathbf{O}`, `\mathcal{O}`, `\mathsf{O}`

`\mathcal{O}` was close but not close enough.

**EDIT:**

`\usepackage{txfonts}` redefines symbols, try to avoid using it if possible. A somewhat dirty hack is found [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&p=24515)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{euscript}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{O}$

\end{document}
```

I.e. `\mathcal{O}`, indeed, but with the package `euscript`.